# Canonical transformation that contains the time as an explicit parameter

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

On the Page 385 of Goldstein's Classical Mechanics book (third edition), it starts to talk a bout the canonical transformation with time as an explicit parameter.

But I don't quite under understand the following argument:

> Considering a canonical transformation of the form 
>   $$\zeta(t) = \zeta(\eta,t),$$ if the transformation 
>   $$\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t)$$ is canonical, then so obviously is the transformation
>   $$\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t_0).$$

Why is the transformation $\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t_0)$ obviously a canonical transformation as well?

Comment: if the transformation is canonical for all $t$ then obviously also for $t=t_0$

Comment: @maze-cooperation: There is no assumption that the the transformation is canonical for all t. Here is only two transformation, one is $\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t)$, the other $\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t_0)$. The transformation $\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t)$ is canonical is not equivalent with for any $t_0$, the transformation $\eta \rightarrow \zeta(t_0)$ is also canonical.